# Refreshing cells using Apps Script (SpreadsheetApp.flush not suitable)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

My script gets all sheets from a source spreadsheet, deletes all sheets from a target spreadsheet, and copies all sheets from the source spreadsheet to the target one.

As per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)), all sheets are then called "Copy of [sheet name]". However, I then loop through the sheets to remove the "Copy of " part.

This raises my problem: since some of the sheets are built using the [query function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) from within google sheets, the query gets messed up with the changing sheet names (it's actually a bit more complicated since the actual query is formed in a different sheet - I can further develop that if needed).

The manual fix for this is to go to the query cell and hit enter: this refreshes the query and fixes the problem. However, I don't want to have to do this to n query cells, across n target spreadsheets.

I've tried using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush())) but it doesn't refresh the query. I need something like `flush` which would force refresh all cells in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you tried copying the formulas from the source sheet after renaming the target sheets? How are you changing the target sheet names that formulas referencing those sheets are not updating?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by changing the sheet name as I copy it and then deleting and pasting the same content in the cells (like what I was doing manually).